# Почему крашится приложение при сохранении настроек?

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь внедрить в приложение возможность сохранения настроек, то есть , если юзер изменил состояние Switch, то при перезапуске приложения данное состояние должно оставаться таким же, как его задал юзер. До этого момента все работало замечательно. теперь при переходе в активити Settings приложение крашится. Ниже приложу код из данного активити.

```
int lightTheme;
    Switch switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);



        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }

    private void setOnCheckedChangeListener(Settings settings) {
    }


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Отслеживание переключения: " + (isChecked ? "on" : "off"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(isChecked){
            lightTheme = 1;
        }
        else{
            lightTheme = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onSaveInstanceState()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        saveInstanceState.putInt("LightTheme", lightTheme);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(saveInstanceState);

        lightTheme = saveInstanceState.getInt("LightTheme");
        if(lightTheme == 1){
            switch1.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            switch1.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

В таких случаях нужно приводить лог падения из `Logcat`.

Но у вас очевидная ошибка, вы пытаетесь найти объект  `findViewById(R.id.switch1)`до того как активити получило View `activity_settings`, и ловите `NullPointerException`

```
    Switch switch1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        //После этой строки нужно искать все View элементы в activity_settings
        switch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @СергейКонар, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него :)